# position of "Addressing concerns over the impact of the release"

Tags: adverbial-phrases, placement

What's the difference between the following sentences? Suppose the sentence occurs in the **third** paragraph of a news report, and the **first** paragraph mentions the decision faces opposition from home and abroad. Which version is more natural?

> a. The prime minister pledged that his administration would ensure the safety levels of the wastewater, addressing concerns over the impact of the release.

> b. Addressing concerns over the impact of the release, the prime minister pledged that his administration would ensure the safety levels of the wastewater.

Answer (score 0):

They are very similar. But there is a little bit of nuance: In the first version (where the clause comes at the end), the journalist is implying that his response was *sufficient and satisfactory*—he successfully addressed the problem, or at least successfully alleviated the concerns. The second version (with the clause at the beginning) only explains why the PM said what he said, and does not imply that he successfully resolved the issue.

Comment: Does the first version necessarily mean the the journalist thinks the prime minister successfuly addressed the problem?

Comment: @Apollyon I actually had a sentence at the end saying that it doesn't necessarily mean that, but after considering it again I decided to remove it. I do think that having at the end does mean the journalist thinks the PM was successful in addressing the concerns.